# How to make a div not move when scrolling?

Tags: html, scroll

I have created this div on the top left of my website, which contains the logo. However, I want it to stay there and not move up and down when I am scrolling. Please advise.

```
<div style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px; height: 140px; width: 150px;">
   <p align="left">
      <img src="images/logo.png" border="5" alt="Logo" />
   </p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: anyway, I owuld suggest to turn it into a stlye ant take it out into a css file

Answer (score 31):

```
<div style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px; height: 140px; width: 150px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0">
```

for ref: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 22):

**position:fixed;**
An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.
It will not move even if the window is scrolled.

so change your css:

```
<div style="position : fixed; padding: 5px 0 0 5px; height: 140px; width: 150px;">
```

Answer (score -2):

Add an id to your div like this:

```
<div style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px; height: 140px; width: 
150px;"id="idOfDiv">
<p align="left"><img src="images/logo.png" border="5" alt="Logo" />
</p>
</div>
```

Add to CSS:

```
#idOfDiv {position:fixed;}
```

Now, it should not scroll with the rest of the page or the parent element.

Example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PJM257/pL1s6jpz/